# How to extend ShapeMenuItem with URL field

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I'd like to use this existing MenuItem to use shapes for certain menu items. However I'd like a field to input URL like Custom Link has. So I've added new Input field to **ShapeMenuItem** ... But so far I'm unable to access it's value in shapes themselves

I've tried

```
<a class="highlight" href="@Model.Content.ContentItem.ShapeMenuItem.Url.Value">@Model.MenuItem.Text</a>
```

But that gives me server error **Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference**

Any ideas?

Comment: Attach a debugger and figure out what is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was just stupid me again in late hours, it's supposed to be

```
@Model.MenuItem.Content.ContentItem.ShapeMenuItem.Url.Value
```